# How do I make Sublime Text 3 my default text editor on Windows 10?

Tags: text, registry, editor, sublimetext3

I know this question has been asked before in various places but I've tried everything and nothing has worked for me. When I select "open with" there is no option for "always open .txt files with this app."

The answer I saw on a few threads on here and elsewhere was to open "regedit" and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open\command` and then "kill explorer.exe" in Task Manager (which I couldn't find...). What I am doing wrong?

Does anyone have an alternate solution to this problem? I just want to be able to click on a text file and immediately be able to use Sublime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First go to the windows settings menu, click on the Apps settings. From there click Default Apps, scroll down until you see "choose default app by file type". Click that option, then scroll to the file extension ".txt", and click the gray plus arrow beside it and select sublime text.

Comment: Does not work for me. It refuses to set to Sublime. If I select something like Wordpad from the popup list, it changes it to that. But if I choose Sublime, it changes it back to Notepad instead.

Comment: The gray plus arrow is not available on mine and Notepad has already been selected, and if I try to change it the pop-up menu only has notepad and WordPad. Looking into app store and searching for sublime also didn't help.

Comment: I figured out why sublime was not showing up in the list. File should at be "open with" sublime first, then it will appear in the list. But still have same issue as Chris Noe.

Comment: Not working here either - Ive tried registry hack here also doesn't work: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/cannot-make-sublime-3-default-editor-windows-10-sept-2018/39426

Answer (score 20):

It's an issue on Windows OS side. Don't worry, I have a fix for you (the only method that works on the Internet):

- Open start menu --> type in cmd --> right click on it and run as administrator
- Depending on where you have your sublime installed, you will have to edit the path, otherwise, copy + paste this line in order to change the .txt extension:

> ftype **txtfile**="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"

You can follow the same logic by always starting with "ftype" in front and then then you will need to find out what is the abbreviation of a chosen extension. You can do that by typing in "assoc **.css**"

For example, .php is PHPfile or .css is CSSfile

[Screenshot here with some more examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOPj3.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Not my answer, but the best I found, UX-wise: https://superuser.com/a/1354363/1034806

> As above, in Windows 10 version 1803, , the control panel shortcut now just brings up Settings.
>
> But the following worked:
>
> Right-click on the file, select "Open With" and click "Choose another app" at the bottom of the right-click menu.
>
> Clicking that gives the dialog box with default app selection that ends with "Look for an app in the Store".
>
> **Here's the tricky bit:** Click on the white space under the last option. This extends the list!
>
> Scroll to the bottom of this list (assuming your app isn't listed).
>
> Click on the white space, under the last option, again!
>
> You should be taken to the Windows standard File Open dialog, where you can browse to your program of choice. (Worked for me.)

Comment: This worked for me except that the "More apps" and "Choose another app on this PC" prompts visible after scrolling. Didn't have to try to find the "magic white space" (hopefully this means it'll be easier for others to follow these instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text is really a great and fast editor which i love for editing text files etc..

So for me a quick workaround was to download/install the 3180 [dev build](https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) and then change the file type association via right click > open with > sublime text 3.

After that is done you can reinstall the 3176 stable build which does not need a license. The registry stays the same. And now a double click should work.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would like to add that if you like the app, after testing it, consider buying a license to support the ongoing of the project.